# Windows equivalents of kill, open_pipe_rw and fork - Trying to compile w3m

Tags: windows, unix, mingw

I'm trying to compile w3m for Windows XP using MinGW or TDM-GCC. After applying the patch at [W3m patch - Linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/w3m.html) and adding **-lws2_32** to LIBS at Makefile I have come across these 5 Windows-incompatible functions (in the order of first appearance)

```
bcopy (at Str.c)
sleep (at file.c)
kill (at image.c)
open_pipe_rw (at image.c)
fork (at image.c)
```

I have fixed the first two by defining their Windows equivalents like:

```
void bcopy(const void *from, void *to, size_t n) {
  int *dummy;
  dummy = memcpy(to, from, n);
}

#define sleep(n) Sleep(n*1000)
```

After these, all object files were compiled fine but those three Unix functions being called from **image.o** prevented w3m.exe from being formed at the linking stage:

```
$ make
(cd libwc && make CC='gcc' OPTS='')
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Documents and Settings/ibm/Downloads/w3m-0.5.3/libwc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Documents and Settings/ibm/Downloads/w3m-0.5.3/libwc'
gcc  -I. -I. -g -O2 -I./libwc -IC:/msys32/usr/local/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DAUXBIN_DIR=\"/usr/local/libexec/w3m\" 
-DCGIBIN_DIR=\"/usr/local/libexec/w3m/cgi-bin\" -DHELP_DIR=\"/usr/local/share/w3m\" -DETC_DIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -DCONF_DIR=\"/usr/local/etc/w3m\" 
-DRC_DIR=\"~/.w3m\" -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" 
-o w3m.exe main.o file.o buffer.o display.o etc.o search.o linein.o 
table.o local.o form.o map.o frame.o rc.o menu.o mailcap.o image.o 
symbol.o entity.o terms.o url.o ftp.o mimehead.o regex.o news.o func.o 
cookie.o history.o backend.o keybind.o anchor.o parsetagx.o tagtable.o 
istream.o version.o  -lws2_32 -lpthread -L. -lindep  -lgc -L./libwc -lwc 
-LC:/msys32/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lncurses
./libindep.a(indep.o): In function `bcopy':
C:\Documents and Settings\ibm\Downloads\w3m-0.5.3/indep.c:74: multiple definition of `bcopy'
./libindep.a(Str.o):C:\Documents and Settings\ibm\Downloads\w3m-0.5.3/Str.c:36: first defined here image.o: In function `closeImgdisplay':
C:\truncated\w3m-0.5.3/image.c:126: undefined reference to `kill'
image.o: In function `openImgdisplay':
C:\truncated\w3m-0.5.3/image.c:93: undefined reference to `open_pipe_rw'
image.o: In function `loadImage':
C:\truncated\w3m-0.5.3/image.c:354: undefined reference to `kill'
C:\truncated\w3m-0.5.3/image.c:383: undefined reference to `kill'
C:\truncated\w3m-0.5.3/image.c:436: undefined reference to `fork'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'w3m.exe' failed
make: *** [w3m.exe] Error 1
```

How can I define the Windows equivalents of those three Unix functions? If you can suggest any other solution like giving specific options to or editing the configure command and/or Makefile so that the *image.c* uses the Windows equivalents of those functions, that's fine too. Thanks.

Comment: There are no 1:1 equivalents for kill or fork, it depends on how the calls are being used.  In the case of fork it is often impossible to port without redesigning the program.  (A Google search for open_file_rw suggests that it is part of a third-party library rather than a standard Linux function.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it's helpful. As you pointed out, in the case of fork, things are a bit tricky and I may have to try hard tweaking the program until they get fixed. I noticed the case about the open_pipe_rw too, being used rarely. I have to find a way to tweak that, too.

Comment: I've found a Windows patch for w3m at http://osdir.com/ml/web.w3m.devel/2006-01/msg00000.html Surely, that's for the previous version of w3m but interestingly it shows how to patch the fork and open_pipe_rw functions. After that information, I noticed that the only module which used those Unix functions was image.o, possibly to support images in the w3m. Then I tried the --disable-image option in configure and that worked out. I got a perfectly compiled and linked w3m.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Build the program for Cygwin; then turn it into a native application with [Cygnal](http://www.kylheku.com/cygnal) by bundling it together with the Cygwin DLL's it needs, but with `cygwin1.dll` from Cygnal instead of Cygwin.

Cygwin has `fork`, `kill` and numerous other POSIX functions.

Also, Cygwin provides bi-directional ANSI/VT100 emulation, right over the Windows Console API.  This means that programs that interact with terminals using raw escape sequences will work—right out of the `cmd.exe` console window. The POSIX `termios` function work nicely for setting up character-at-a-time input and all that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but any compilation done with the Cygwin does not count as a real Windows application. Currently, the patched w3m I built with TDM-GCC works perfectly even on the Windows XP command line.

Comment: Which issue in Cygwin, that is not corrected in Cygnal, or not adequately, makes applications not count as real Windows applications? I'd like to add that issue to the list and work on it. Or is this some emotional thing?

Comment: TDM-GCC or MinGW is the preferred way to go because whenever a package can be built with MinGW, I prefer it over Cygwin and in the case of w3m I could built it with MinGW/TDM-GCC. Having said that, I'll try the Cygnal next time I run into similar issues because it looks interesting and well suited to the task. Remember: I've built w3m before I knew about Cygnal. Btw, I appreciate your work on TXR too as I'm interested in scraping tasks. I might give it a try, too.